# Border Container regions dont display properly in custom widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I've got a dojo custom widget using a template with border container and content panes with top, leading, center, trailing and bottom regions.  The problem is that the content panes are displaying top to bottom, not in the correct layout format:

here is my template:

```
<div>
 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'">Leading pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">Center pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'">Trailing pane</div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">Bottom pane</div>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my widget:

```
define([
  "dojo/_base/declare",
  "dijit/_WidgetBase",
  "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
  "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
  "dojo/text!Templates/LandUse.htm",
   "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/TitlePane",
], function (declare, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin, LandUseTpl, registry) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {
        templateString: LandUseTpl
    });
});
```

The main page where the template is being called and inserted:

```
<script>
...
LU = new LandUse({}, "tool");
...
</script>
<body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" id="Main" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
     <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="TOC" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'leading'">
     </div>
     <div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="Content" data-dojo-props="splitter: true, region:'center'">
     <div id="tool"></div> <!--here is the insertion point-->
     </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Any thoughts why this displays as:

Top pane

Leading pane

Center pane

Trailing pane

Bottom pane

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` does not support layout widgets like the `BorderContainer`:

> The dijit._WidgetsInTemplateMixin mixin does not support adding layout
>   widgets as children. In particular there are issues with startup() and
>   resize() calls to the children.

For some reason, it throws an error in your console saying that the `BorderContainer` you want to register, is already registered. And because the widget does not render properly, it shows the plain HTML in stead, and that's the result you can see.

The proper solution is not to use layout widgets in your template, but what also seems to work is to use your widgets declaratively. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/8vdu1u72/

Comment: ok, Thank you.  I wonder if this will become supported.  It sure would come in handy!